# Why this brain.js script is going too laggy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, neural-network, brain.js

Hello i'm following a browser brain.js script's example and this is the example code:

```
<script src="brain-controller.js"></script>
<script>
net = new brain.recurrent.LSTM()

net.train([
  'doe, a deer, a female deer',
  'ray, a drop of golden sun',
  'me, a name I call myself',
])

output = net.run('doe') // ', a deer, a female deer'
console.log(output)
</script>
```

`brain-controller.js` is the brain.js script updated, so please, DON'T USE CDNJS SCRIPT!!! It is bad! So this is bad too and doesn't works well. I can't run brainjs script in nodejs it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'LSTM' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alumno_ciclo\bot1.js:1:46)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:67:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m
```

When I do `npm install brain.js` it gives me those errors:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: No se pudo cargar el componente "VCBuild.exe" de Visual C++. Para corregir este problema, 1) i
nstale .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) instale Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 o 3) agregue la ubicación del componente a la ru
ta de acceso del sistema si está instalado en otro lugar.  [C:\Users\usuario\node_modules\gl\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\usuario\node_modules\gl
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN mygamename@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN mygamename@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN mygamename@0.0.1 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gl@4.4.1 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gl@4.4.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-07T14_09_02_546Z-debug.log
```

What I should do???

Comment: it would be useful if you add the version that you are using.

Comment: That error is telling you `brain.recurrent` is undefined. Are you sure you're importing the library properly? If this is node.js you'll need to install it with `npm install --save brain.js`

Comment: When I do `npm install brain.js` it gives me a couple of errors.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I added the errors to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have the library imported incorrectly. You can see here your code works using the CDN. Specify the number of iterations (the default is 20,000 (see [here](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js#for-training-with-rnn-lstm-and-gru))) and/or error threshold for faster performance.

```js
function test() {
  net = new brain.recurrent.LSTM()

  net.train([
    'doe, a deer, a female deer',
    'ray, a drop of golden sun',
    'me, a name I call myself',
  ], {
    iterations: 1500,
    log: details => console.log(details),
    errorThresh: 0.011
  });

  output = net.run('doe') // ', a deer, a female deer'
  const myOutput = document.querySelector('#myOutput');
  myOutput.innerHTML = output;
  console.log(output)
}

test();
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/brain.js"></script>
<div id=myOutput></div>
```